# High Content Download Timing for Laravel app

Tags: laravel, optimization, networking

We have a laravel 5.5 application that is currently experiencing high page load/api response timings.
Browser DevTools show very high timings for "Content Download".

[image: devtools]

This works fine in development and we don't see any speed bottlenecks on our APIs or routes. But prod and staging sites are both affected (they are on the same server though).
Our traffic is pretty much the same, nor have we deployed any features that could be so time consuming. All routes and APIs seem to be affected by this.

We tried adding some logging to the index.php file and come to see the `kernel->terminate` calls are taking a while to process.

[image: logs]

Does anyone have any pointers on how can we go about debugging/solving this further?

Comment: Well... that content download is still with an Api task. Just keep that in mind. See if you have the same problem with accessing the api with postman

Comment: I [checked via postman](https://imgur.com/gallery/asD2OYI) as well and see the same problem. The response payload here is 16kB and a 4s download time doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Show the function of that task in your Laravel application. If you can't, because it's sensitive, just reproduce the problem in a separate application that doesn't show thr sensitive information. Right now you have the confirmation: "Yep it's slow while downloading that content"

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the problem in a separate application and share it. Although, the problem isn't with just this one API or function. It's a problem we're seeing for all requests/routes/APIs in the entire application not just this one particular function.